# How to select records starting from last month to 12 months ago?

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select all the records starting from last month to 12 months ago. So when now is **2015-07-09**, I would need to select records between **2014-08-01 and  2015-06-30.**

Comment: Investigated the `DATE_ADD` function at all?

Comment: And you probably meant between 2014-07-01 and 2015-06-30 if you are going to cover 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
select * from  table_name where date_column between date_sub(ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)), 1), interval 1 month) ,  last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month))
```

Comment: here date_column is the column in table containing date value of the type date.

Comment: this would not work properly as it would give from 2014-07-09 to 2015-06-09.

Comment: Does not work either.  By ADDDATE and SUBDATE, i think you mean date_add and date_sub.  Why would you have two date subtractions in the first part, subtracting 11 months and then subtracting one month.  And finding the last day of the month and then adding  one month does not work because for a month like february, that would give you march 28 which is not the last day of march.  Why not just do the last day of 13 months ago?  And using BETWEEN will also not work because it tests for >= and <=.  You really need to test for > last day of the month 13 months ago, and < first day of this month.

Comment: i checked this on my mysql version 5.6 and all working fine as per the requireemnt in the question. can you please try by selecting just the dates?

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month))
                
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: whats the mysql version ?  and also try in Upper case, i think this will be problematic in your version..

Comment: @Aman, you are right about the ADDDATE and SUBDATE being ok.  I did not know Mysql had those synonyms for date_add and date_sub.  But your date math is still probably wrong as the first part evaluates to 2014-08-01, and the OP probably meant 2014-07-01, and 'BETWEEN' is still a problem as his datetime column likely has something like '2015-06-30 08:27:30' in it.  Is that <= to '2015-06-30'?  All the datetimes that have a time part in them, in that last day, would be ommitted.  That is why you have to use less.than '2015-07-01' rather than using less.than.or.equal which is what BETWEEN does.

Comment: This is really too much for me :( I'm just getting started with MySql and can manage simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you up to the end of last month.

```
select ... from table where mydate < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate())-1 day)
```

This should point you in the right direction for what to learn about date math so you can figure out what to do to also test for beginning of 12 months ago (hint: subtract 12 months from the expression I have above and test for greater than or equal to that).

Comment: Unfortunately i'm stuck as i'm not very good at sql queries. I can manage some simple ones, but this is too much for me :) Seems that it's harder than i first thought :(